# N x N Tic Tac Toe Check For Win

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

for the last 2 days I've been trying to make an N x N Tic Tac Toe game and i have a problem that i didn't understand why this problem is happening and I'll be so happy if someone can help me solving this issue. the problem is when i check for Horizontal Win my program checks only the first row and don't check other rows. Here is the function i used to check the horizontal win:

```
void HorizontalWin()
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<size; ++j){
            if(board[i-1][j-1]==board[i-1][j] && board[i][j]!='_')
                horizontal=1;
            else {
                horizontal=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (horizontal==1)
            break;
    }
}
```

size:is the size of the grid and its taken from the user.

Comment: you most likely need to move the horizontal=0 up one loop, else you always overwrite your results!

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a bad idea when a function uses global variables though it can be defined without an access to the global variables.

Nevertheless your function can be defined the following way

```
void HorizontalWin()
{
    horizontal = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; !horizontal && i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( board[i][0] != '_' )
        {
            int j = 1;
            while ( j < size && board[i][j] == board[i][0] ) j++;
            horizontal = j == size;
        }
    }
}
```

As for your function implementation then it has undefined behavior because at least in this if statement

```
if(board[i-1][j-1]==board[i-1][j] && board[i][j]!='_')
```

there is an attempt to access the memory beyond the array when i or j are equal to 0.